Grouping blood tests - Probability Expectation
I've been dealing with the following question: 
A number of people are to pass a blood test each. 
The test may be held in one of two ways:
(1) Each person is tested separately.
(2) The group is divided into groups of size k each.
(Assume the whole group to be large, so that we may neglect the inaccuracy due to the fact that the total size is not exactly divisible by k). 
The blood samples of the people in each of these groups are pooled and analyzed together. If the test
is negative, this one test shows that the result is negative for each of the k people, and the test
suffices. If it is positive, each of the k people must be tested separately, in which case k + 1 tests
are required in all for the k people.
Assume that the probability p that the test yields a positive result for a person is the same for all
people and that distinct people are independent.
Now i have the following 2 questions:
(a) What is the expected value of the number X of tests carried out per person under plan (2)?
(b) For small $p$, show that the value of k which will minimize $E(X)$ is approximately $\frac{1}{\sqrt{p}}$.
The thing is, I was defining X to the number of the expected number of blood test certain person done. So X takes the values 1 or 2, and $P(X=1) = (1-p)^k$ and $P(x=2) = 1 - (1-p)^k$ So  in total we get that $E[X] = 1 \cdot (1-p)^k + 2 \cdot(1-(1-p)^k)$, but they defined X to be exepcted number of blood tests within this group so their definition was $E[X] = 1 \cdot (1-p)^k + (k+1) \cdot(1-(1-p)^k)$ and then they divided $E[X]$ by k as for the expected value per person. What's the difference, And why do we get different results, why my approach wasn't correct?

You're double-counting the combined test.
You've counted it $k$ times aross $k$ people, but we only did 1 test.
Had you weighted the combined test as $1/k$ times for a person, then you would have obtained the same answer as theirs.

Hello, I am not certain where I committed double counting, for a certain person, I know he would either have 1 or 2 blood tests, so I directly calculated each person expected tests, which brings me to this answer: $E[X] = 1 \cdot (1-p)^k + 2 \cdot(1-(1-p)^k)$ where were the double counting done here?

@user1516674 Amongst the $k$ people, consider just the case when they only took 1 combined test. You say that each person takes 1 tests and summing it up across k people means that there are $k$ tests. However, we know that there is just 1 test taken.

But again, I'm looking at particular person, and calculating his expected value, by definition. I don't understand what you clarify, can you elaborate more please?

@user1516674 let me try a different skinning.  Suppose a school has a final exam for 10 students set on Jan 1. How many days does the school give the exam? Your solution is akin to saying "Each student takes the exam on 1 day. So there are 10 days that the exam is given." However, clearly the exam is only given on 1 day. $\quad$ Now, suppose the school has a final exam on Jan 1. If a student fails, they can try again on Jan 5. What's the expected number of days that the school gives an exam? Each student takes the exam on 1 or 2 days, so is the expected number of exam days between 10 and 20?

But earlier you said i should combine 1/k for a person, When i do it on my solution it doesn't make sense and i don't get the same solution as the original. And i don't how the example you gave is the same

Your $E(X)$ should be $(1/k)(1-p)^k + (1/k+1) [ 1 - (1-p)^k] $ because the combined test needs to be weighted as $1/k$ in both situations. When you multiply that by $k$, you get their expression for $E(X)$. $\quad$ The example I gave was not a perfect match, but just meant to illustrate the error in your thinking. This reskinning is now a closer match. Now suppose the school has a final exam on Jan 1 for $k$ students. If ANY student fails, then all must try again on Jan 5. What is the expected number of days that the school gives an example? Is it between 1 and 2, or between $k$ and $2k$?

I think I got it, basically what I did was referring the first test(the whole group as once test) as each person took it(so it multiplied by k), and that's why I got it wrong, thanks!

@user1516674 Yup. And that's also why we can fix it by counting that test as $1/k$ times for a person.
